# How can i show and edit "read more" button using underscores.me

Tags: wordpress

so i am doing this site with underscore.me but i am lost on how to get to show the read more on blog list page(index.php). 
i want the post to be summarised and the user will have to click on read more in order to get the blog page But right now it only show a bracket and 3 dots inside.[bracket with 3 dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEVQg.png)

I look inside content.php if i can find whenre to edit to get my desired results but right now i am not sure. Cont

Answer (score 0):

WordPress excerpts, by default, display {...} to indicate that there is more to read. This is changed via a [WordPress filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_the_Read_More_text_when_using_the_the_excerpt.28.29) using a few lines of code.

Fortunately, there are [plenty of plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/excerpts/) that you can install that will do this for you.